# How can I select a window in overview mode (Meta + w) using the keyboard?

Tags: window-management

I am a frequent user of the overview mode provided by `Meta + w`. There I can select a window by using left mouse click on the window.

Is it also possible to select a window using only the keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seems like there is such functionality... instead I can suggest you to use Super + Arrow Down, you'll be able to select the window with arrow keys, and "Select" with Enter button.

And, it sounds like a feature request to me :) Submit it to Launchpad as a blueprint?

Comment: Cool feature! I wasn't aware of `Super + Arrow Down`. Thanks for suggesting!